# Django JWT authentication doesn't work in browser?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm trying to do django authentication with JWT in my django+react app. I'm using part 1 of this tutorial: https://hackernoon.com/110percent-complete-jwt-authentication-with-django-and-react-2020-iejq34ta
Everything works fine when I use cURL in terminal to get access to my API, but when I run server in my browser I'm still getting
[image: "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."]

What does this behaviour mean?

Comment: You need to pass jwt token as authorization header in your request

Comment: @Muhammadhassan I have headers added in my request (authentication, content-type and accept) but still no luck

Comment: @silvaa11 does your header key corect? i think it should be Authorization if you didn't override

Comment: The correct way of passing jwt token is: Authorization: Bearer <JWT TOKEN>. Here Authorization is the key and "Bearer <JWT Token>" is the value. Are u using the same way?

Comment: @Muhammadhassan in my settings file I have `'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),` but it only changes displayed header to `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api"`